# Pandas use several rows for a column MultiIndex in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

When you load a CSV in pandas you can easily specify the number of rows to use as column indexes, as such:

```
import pandas
from six import StringIO
df = """a | X | X  | Y | Y  | Z  | Z
        b | C | N  | C | N  | C  | N
        c | i | i  | i | j  | j  | j
        d | 3 | 10 | 4 | 98 | 81 | 0"""
df = StringIO(df.replace(' ',''))
df = pandas.read_csv(df, sep="|", header=[0,1,2])

>>> df
   a  X      Y       Z
   b  C   N  C   N   C  N
   c  i   i  i   j   j  j
0  d  3  10  4  98  81  0
```

But how do you produce the same result from a Dataframe in memory? How do you simply specifying which set of rows should be used for the column index ?

Without of course going through this hack:

```
>>> df

   0  1   2  3   4   5  6
0  a  X   X  Y   Y   Z  Z
1  b  C   N  C   N   C  N
2  c  i   i  i   j   j  j
3  d  3  10  4  98  81  0

path = '~/test/temp.csv'
df.to_csv(path, header=None, index=None)
df = pandas.read_csv(path, header=[0,1,2])
```

Or even this hack:

```
>>> df

   0  1   2  3   4   5  6
0  a  X   X  Y   Y   Z  Z
1  b  C   N  C   N   C  N
2  c  i   i  i   j   j  j
3  d  3  10  4  98  81  0

df = df.transpose().set_index([0,1,2]).transpose()
```

I tried using this method, but it does not accept an `axis` parameter:

```
df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternative solution should be improved a bit:

```
df = df.T.set_index([0,1,2]).T
```

Another solution without transpose:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.iloc[:3].apply(tuple))
df = df.iloc[3:].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  X      Y       Z   
   b  C   N  C   N   C  N
   c  i   i  i   j   j  j
0  d  3  10  4  98  81  0
```